# Can't figure out what is wrong here.. Angular JS Error - Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: html, angularjs

I am simply trying to define an angular module, and refer it in html. I am unable to figure out what is wrong. The angular.min.js file is in the same folder as the app.js file.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Shopping List Check Off</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src = "js/angular.min.js" </script>
      <script src = "js/app.js" </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
   </head>
   <body ng-app="apply">
      <h1> This is test page </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here are the contents of the app.js file

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('apply',[])
 })();
```

Would appreciate any response.
Thanks.

Comment: properly close your `!doctype html>`,`<script` tags in your `html file` first, then it will work without an issue

Comment: Thanks much. The script lines didn't have closing tags before </script>. Thanks, I knew I was missing something obvious.

Comment: You are welcome, accept it as an answer, so that it will help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing **`<`** at the start also ,You should have a ; at the end of the module,

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('apply', []);
})();
```

**DEMO**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('apply', []);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="apply">
  <h1> This is test page </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

View source (Ctrl+u) and see if you can access Angular.min.js by clicking on it. Or simply use

```
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
```